# Unable to get third level records filtered using Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have the below code structure and would like to get all the record from Unit collection where `AmountIsTaxInclusive` is true

```
public class Unit
{
    [Key, DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int UnitID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int UnitStatusID { get; set; }
    public virtual Reservation Reservation { get; set; }

}

public class Reservation
{
    [Key, DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int ReservationID { get; set; }

    public int ReservationStatusID { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<ReservationUnits> ReservationUnits

}

public class ReservationUnit 
{
    [Key, DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int ReservationUnitID { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public int ReservationID { get; set; }
    public Reservation Reservation { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public int UnitID { get; set; }
    public Unit Unit { get; set; }

    public decimal Amount { get; set; }
    public bool AmountIsTaxInclusive { get; set; }
    public bool IsFixedRate { get; set; }
}
```

When I tried to filter `Reservationunit` collection I am getting all records.

Query

```
var result = _unitOfWork.UnitRepository.GetBySessionIdAndUnit(sessionId, newUnitIds).IncludeFilter(p => p.Reservation).IncludeFilter(y => y.Reservation.ReservationUnit.Where(c => c.AmountIsTaxInclusive  == true)).ToList();
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.
Please take the [tour] to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [ask] on how to improve the quality of your question.
Then [edit] your question to include your source code as a [mcve], which can be compiled and tested by others.
Please show your attempts you have tried and the problems/error messages you get from your attempts.

Comment: Could you further describe "When i tried to filter ... I am unable to do so?" Why are you not able to do it?

Comment: How many records are you getting all or none? for me I am getting all records and it is not filtering the records based on condition.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is simple. You just need to make an instance of your Context class(let us name it dbContext).
Then call the following line where you want.

```
var myDesiredList = dbContext.ReservationUnit.where( ru => ru.AmountIsTaxInclusive == true).ToList();
```

Let me know if you had more information to share.

Comment: Requirement is to get all the unit records along with the filter reservationunit records in a single return from entity framework.

Comment: If you just need the Units, tou can do: `var myDesiredList = dbContext.ReservationUnit.Where( ru => ru.AmountIsTaxInclusive == true).Select(r => r.Unit).ToList();`

Comment: it will work on Reservation unit and it will not return the unit item collection. how it can give it.. kindly suggest